# What is this thing in Visual Studio Code called and how to disable it

Tags: visual-studio-code, popup, intellisense, autosuggest, ergonomics

sorry that I don't know how to refer to it. Pls see the image. When I type in vscode, this annoying popup keeps blocking my view to see the code above. I am new in this so I need to refer to the previous lines. maybe when I am more experienced, I don't need to do this anymore. But right now, I want to disable it! Could anyone tell me what it is and how to disable it? [image]Thanks!

Comment: looks like the tooltip of the red squiggle, you can use Esc and fix the error

Comment: it worked beautifully! since it is only temporarily disabling it, i don't need to worry about activating it again in the future. thanks!